# Does ensemble interpretation of QM involve hidden variables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

The ensemble interpretation of quantum mechanics considers the quantum state description to apply only to an ensemble of similarly prepared systems, rather than supposing that it exhaustively represents an individual physical system. (Wikipedia).

But ensembles involve many similar but different systems. What else but systems with different hidden variables may quantum ensemble include?

Comment: Ensembles, whether statistical, thermodynamic or quantum mechanical only exist on paper. If the resulting theory makes predictions that agree well enough with experiments on individual systems, then the physicist is happy. By well enough we mean that it would be pointless to look for correlations (aka "hidden variables") that shouldn't exist according to the theory because the necessary statistical power to identify them does not exist in the data.

Answer (score 1):

The ensemble interpretation is just a handwaving, even compared to other fuzzy interpretations. In fact, it is not so much an interpretation as a refusal to interpret. Thus, it is difficult to answer any meaningful deep question about this interpretation, including the hidden variables one.

Comment: I disagree that "ensemble interpretation is just a handwaving". I think modern people forgot ensemble interpretation and most of them can't explain it, giving only general formal statements, like wikipedia does. I want examples of using wavefunction to describe an ensemble.

Comment: @kludg, there are no such examples. The behavior of real ensembles is classical, not quantum. Physicists use the concept of ensembles to interpret classical probabilities, and when physicists faced quantum probabilities, some of them tried to apply the same idea. But this idea did not lead to anything, and nothing concrete can be said about such imagined quantum ensembles.

Answer (score 0):

I think ensemble interpretation assumes that the wavefunction describes behaviour of a system of particles called ensemble. This is not exactly ensemble as the term is used in statistical physics which led me to confusion. The purpose is to avoid strange things like particle interfering with itself, we consider only interference of different particles.

For example if we consider radioactive decay of macroscopic number of atoms, we can say that after half-life time half of the atoms will decay, but we can say nothing about an individual atom. Not even that it will decay with 50% probability.

I think this is clever idea but physicists experiment now with
individual particles so the future of ensemble interpretation is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

The ensemble interpretation of quantum mechanics has some problems related to the question you asked.

If we take quantum mechanics as being an accurate description of reality, then systems are similarly prepared if they have the same quantum state. And we have explanations of how to produce systems in quantum states and what is happening in reality in quantum mechanical experiments. Attempts to perform experiments can then be judged by coming up with explanations of how to check whether the experiment has been set up correctly.

Advocates of the ensemble interpretation don't say what is happening in reality to produce the results predicted by quantum mechanics, so they have no way of specifying what it means for systems to be identically prepared. Nor do they have any means of saying whether an experiment has been performed correctly since they have no description of what is happening in the experiment. So the ensemble interpretation can't be used to perform or interpret experiments, which is a problem for a theory that claims to be an interpretation.

As for hidden variables, since no theory of hidden variables exists, it doesn't make much sense to speculate about what such a theory would predict. Also, the advocates of the ensemble interpretation would ignore any such theory since they don't want to say anything about how the world actually works.

Comment: Please don't say  that hidden variable theorizes don't exist  or other trivial things, This is not whst is asked here.

Comment: Your question asks: "What else but systems with different hidden variables may quantum ensemble include?" Since no such theory doesn't exist it shouldn't be regarded as a candidate for understanding quantum mechanics.